# Is there a way to let the user itself delete its AzureB2C account?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I'm looking for a way to let the user delete their AzureB2C user account out of an iOS/Android mobile app. I use at the moment the MSAL lib from Microsoft to let the user create, login and change their password within the app.

Starting from now Apple defined a new AppStore requirement:
5.1.1(v): Apps supporting account creation must also offer account deletion.

So I was looking into ways to let the user delete their account out of the app. But It seems that there is no user flow for this right now.

Are there any plans to add a "Delete account" user flow? Or did I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a sample for a user journey that allows a user to delete their account here:

https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/delete-my-account

It only is possible with custom policies.

Otherwise your application needs to call MS Graph API and delete the users account from the directory.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-delete?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http